# Inverse of `Module#singleton_class`

Tags: ruby, class, singleton

What is the inverse of `Module#singleton_class`? I.e., given a singleton class, how can I get the module it is the singleton of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ObjectSpace#each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) for that:

```
module M; end
sc = M.singleton_class

ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).find { |m| m.singleton_class == sc }
  #=> M
```

@ndn pointed out that:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(sc).to_a #=> [M]
```

so it's just:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(sc).first #=> M
```

Comment: It turns out that `each_object(sc)` does not always give the right result.