# How to find the wrapped class name of a singleton class?

Tags: ruby

Given a `self` as below, how to find its class name:

```
self = #<Class:#<PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest:0x0000000b2a3400>>
```

What I am looking for is to return `PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest`. `self.name (nil)` and `self.class.name (Class)` do not return the right answer. Here is more info about the `self`:

[image]

How can I retrieve `PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest`?

Comment: Where are you getting `self` from? What's the context?

Comment: self is from singleton class. It is an instance of `PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest`

Comment: The guy who down vote it, do you know the right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the only instance of a singleton class, you can find it in `ObjectSpace`.

```
some_singleton_class = some_obj.singleton_class

some_obj_2 = ObjectSpace.each_object(some_singleton_class).first

some_obj_2.object_id == some_obj.object_id  #=> true
```

If your `self` is a class's singleton class, then the class you're searching for is the only instance of that singleton class.

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(self).first.name  #=> should return "PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest"
```

This approach may not be fast so avoid using it whenever possible.

**WARNING**: If the class you want has subclasses, then this approach will not work. For example

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Object.singleton_class).to_a
```

will return a huge amount of classes (think why).

### UPDATE

You can do further filter from the search result from `ObjectSpace`.

```
def instance_of(singleton_class)
  ObjectSpace.each_object(singleton_class).find do |obj|
    obj.singleton_class == singleton_class
  end
end

instance_of(Object.singleton_class)  #=> Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspection of the form:

```
#<Class:#<SomeModule>>
```

indicates the singleton class of `SomeModule`. When `SomeModule` is actually an anonymous instance of a module, it looks like this:

```
a = Module.new
# => #<Module:0x007f6f86eb8fa0>
a.singleton_class
# => #<Class:#<Module:0x007f6f86eb8fa0>>
```

You have an anonymous class that is the singleton class of an anonymous instance `0x0000000b2a3400` of `PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest`, which must be a module. You cannot name a singleton class, so you cannot get its name.

On getting the original module of a singleton class, follow  an answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488903).

Comment: mm, odd. I can see the name in self. `PaymentRequestx` is a rails engine name and `payment_request` is the table name in the engine.

Answer (score 0):

As of Ruby 3.2 ([issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12084), [PR](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/6450)), there is now a new API which makes this a breeze: [`Class#attached_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Class.html#method-i-allocate)

Demo:

```rb
module PaymentRequestx
  class PaymentRequest; end
end

some_singleton_class = PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest.new.singleton_class

# #<Class:#<PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest:0x00000001050ab3a0>>
p some_singleton_class

# "PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest"
p some_singleton_class.attached_object.class.name
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `self.ancestors.first.name`

[`:ancestors`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) returns a list of modules prepended or included to whatever it's called on.

Comment: `self.ancestors.first` returns exactly the same as `self` which is `#<Class:#<PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest:0x0000000b2a3400>>`

Comment: Hmm, it works for me locally though. `irb(main):078:0> c
=> #<Class:#<A::B:0x007fea739e07b8>>
irb(main):079:0> c.ancestors.first
=> A::B` Please update your question to show exactly what the context is. How are the classes defined?

Comment: What does `self.ancestors` return?

Comment: self.ancestors return an array. The class name is there but can not be retrieved.odd.

Comment: What do you mean, it cannot be retrieved? If you have an array, then you can access any element of the array, can you not?

Comment: The array values are classes and modules. Not a simple string. Just like `self` returns a class.

Comment: Well then, call `name` on it.